# Convert dynamically created checkbox input to Switchery-style switch

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, switchery

I need to dynamically create a [Switchery](https://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/) switch.

I'm creating non-dynamic switches like this:

```
<div class="item form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Admin User</label>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" id= "canModify"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this works just fine.

However when I create the same structure via JavaScript like this:

```
  html = '<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" id= "' + elementID +  '"/>'
```

I get these results:

[image: Not loading the look of the js-switch]

The one below was statically added, and it appears correctly. The one above generated dynamically, but it appears only as a check box. So my question is, how do I solve this?

Comment: It would be good if you include the JavaScript that loads and calls Switchery.

Comment: I never "call" switchery. Just load the library with <script src="../vendors/switchery/dist/switchery.min.js"></script> and that is it. (This is at the bottom of the HTML file.

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding a new input to the DOM with `class="js-switch"` will not create a [Switchery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/switchery-latest)-style switch.

A JavaScript Switchery object must be created for each input.

This function will convert all non-switchery inputs in the DOM to Switchery-style switches:

```js
// convert all inputs with class="js-switch" to Switchery
function convertToSwitchery() {

  // get all "js-switch" class inputs in the DOM
  const jsSwitchInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch');

  jsSwitchInputs.forEach(input => {
    // ignore if input is already switchery
    if (input.dataset.switchery) {
      return;
    }
    // create new Switchery object
    new Switchery(input);
  });
}
```

A working example:

```js
// convert all inputs with class="js-switch" to Switchery-style
function convertToSwitchery() {
  const jsSwitchInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch');
  jsSwitchInputs.forEach(input => {
    // ignore if input is already switchery
    if (input.dataset.switchery) {
      return;
    }
    new Switchery(input);
  });
}



// code for demo only:
const divResult = document.getElementById('result');
let iButton = 0;

// add a new "js-switch" input
function addInput() {
  const br = document.createElement('br');
  divResult.appendChild(br);
  const label = document.createElement('label');
  label.for = `input${++iButton}`;
  label.className = 'mr-4';
  label.innerHTML = `Dynamic "js-switch" ${iButton} `;
  divResult.appendChild(label);
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'checkbox';
  input.className = 'js-switch';
  input.id = `input${iButton}`;
  divResult.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/switchery-latest@0.8.2/switchery.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="p-4">
  <h4>Convert Checkbox Inputs to Switchery Style</h4>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="addInput();">
    Add ".js-switch"</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
    onclick="convertToSwitchery();">
    Convert All to Switchery</button>
    
  <div class="mt-4" id="result">
    <label for="static-input">Static "js-switch"</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" checked />
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/switchery-latest@0.8.2/dist/switchery.min.js"></script>
```

References:

- [Switchery on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/switchery-latest)

Comment: This did not work. It did nothing. is the variable supposed to be assigned somewhere. The html is part of a form application, in case it matters....

Comment: @aarelovich I updated the answer to include a general-purpose solution with a working demo.

Comment: Thank you. It's important so it will help someone else

Comment: BTW, Bootstrap has a built-in custom switch class called `custom-switch`. It's almost identical to Switchery, with no JavaScript needed. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#switches

Comment: I only I had know before! Thanks!

Comment: I have not tried it, myself and after much grief with these infernat switches I switched to bootstrap switches (but no the one sin you link as the version of bootstrap currently used by my webpage is too old and updating it put all sorts of things out of whack). It is why I have not accepted it. Should I anyways?

Comment: I answered your question correctly and completely, and the working code snippet proves it.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the documentation I did find somehting that worked.

I need to first add the code to the actual elment that will contain the switch.

```
   document.getElementById("mainPanel").innerHTML = html;
```

Only after the code is added I can enable switchery using these two lines, copied and pasted from the documentantion

```
   // This is required to enable Switchery. 
   var elem = document.querySelector('.js-switch');
   var init = new Switchery(elem);
```

Hope this helps someone else!